# $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

$[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]$ because

$$[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}=\bigcap_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}[0,1]\setminus\{q\}$$

However, is it $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Can't you just replace $[0,1]$ with $(0,1)$ on the right-hand side of that equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about fixing an enumeration of $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ as $q_1,q_2,\dots$, then

$$[0,1]\backslash \mathbb Q=\bigcap_n \left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\backslash \{q_n\}$$

Comment: Do U mean $A=[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your set is  $$(0,1)\cap\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb Q}(\mathbb R\setminus\{q\}).$$